# Trying to import an npm module (Howler) in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, howler.js

I am trying to import Howler inside my angular 2 app, but it does not have a typings file. I am confused and have been searching for the answer, but cannot find anything. How do I go about importing "howler" inside my component without a typings file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) typings definition for howler.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/howler) on GitHub where you can find `howler.d.ts`

Here is the npm [package info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ryancavanaugh/howlerjs)

TypeScript v2 use following command to install

```
npm install --save @types/howler
```

If you have any question, post in their [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge)

Comment: Does not work with NextJS.