# Howler: Angular error TS2304: Cannot find name "Howl"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am referencing [Howler](https://howlerjs.com/) in my index.html file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.3/howler.min.js"></script>
```

Then in my `app.component.ts` I have the line:

```
let sound = new Howl({src: [sample]});
```

This produces the error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Howl'.

I tried including it in the `lib` array in `tsconfig.json` but that is not permitted.

Comment: What happens if you add `declare const Howl` above your `@Component` and below the `import`...?

Comment: @Ivaro18 that (almost) worked, I had to add the type. So `declare const Howl:any` works. Feel free to add as answer & I'll mark correct.

Comment: Or, as you say, the other SO question answers this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) typings definition for howler.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/howler) on GitHub where you can find `howler.d.ts`

Here is the npm [package info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ryancavanaugh/howlerjs)

TypeScript v2 use following command to install

```
npm install --save @types/howler
```

If you have any question, post in their [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge)

Comment: copied answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195167/2343242